# Using JWPLAYER 5, Play video from specific time one from another page

Tags: jwplayer

I am using jwplayer 5.
I have two html pages, one the scene select and other is play movie.
Scene select page has four videos with names chapter 1, chapter 2, chapter 3 and chapter 4.
And on play movie there is one video full screen.
Now my requirement is when someone is on scene select page and click on chapter 1 than it will be go to play movie page and play movie to specific time lets stay movie will start from 30 mins.

Can anyone please help.
Pages can been seen here:
http://coderhtml.coffeecup.com/mywork/USB-stick-Motion/scene-select.html
http://coderhtml.coffeecup.com/mywork/USB-stick-Motion/play-movie.html

Answer (score 0):

JW Player 5 is no longer supported, please update to JW8. You can sign up for a free developer account - https://developer.jwplayer.com/

Here is a demo showing how to have hot links and seek to specific parts in a video - http://qa.jwplayer.com/~fabian/frame_tool.html but this will not work with JW5.